# PCA - determine principal components

Tags: r

I am trying to make a PCA, but I am missing something.

Calculated the eigenvalues and made the plot. So, I see that there are a lot of components. The point is that I do not know how to figure out which components are the principal ones...

[image]

Comment: It seems that the first four or five points account for most of the variation.

Comment: Please review basic statistics textbooks on PCA. You'll probably want to use the so-called "elbow method". This is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow for many reasons, including content, lack of self-research, and format.

Comment: If you use 'prcomp' function of built-in 'stats' package of R, summary of your PCA results will print the total variance explained for each components. Check the link: https://www.r-bloggers.com/computing-and-visualizing-pca-in-r/

Answer (score 1):

This depends totally on the application.

1. If you are doing PCA as a pre processing step to supervised learning, than the optimal number of PCA dimensions should be chosen by cross validation / validation.
2. If you are using PCA as an unsupervised method to explore and visualize the data then several options exist:

   - hard cap of a certain variance explained like 80% (in your case it looks like 4- 5 PCs should do)
   - Cattell's scree test says to drop all further components after the one starting the elbow. (in your case 2 PCs should be kept)
   - Kaiser criterion: The Kaiser rule is to drop all components with eigenvalues under 1.0 (as I remember Kaiser said he was misquoted on that one).
   - Horn's parallel analyses (yeah a real analyses not some elbow rule) - here's a link on how to perform it in R: https://www.r-bloggers.com/determining-the-number-of-factors-with-parallel-analysis-in-r/

Comment: isn't Horn's parallel analyses used for factor analysis?

Comment: From the documentation of paran: paran is an implementation of Horn's technique for
numerically and graphically evaluating the components or
factors retained in a principle components analysis (PCA) or
common factor analysis (FA). https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/paran/paran.pdf

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I did not know that this method was existed. I had this arbitrary data (95 observations and 27 variables) and run prcomp of stats package in R, on this dataset and got 15 different components with 95% total variance explained. Now, I run Horn's technique on the same data and it gives me 7 factors retained, which is weird. Thus, what does it show? Am I making mistake with my analysis? or which number of components should I go for? 15 or 7?

Comment: It means that each of the first 7 PCs explains more than random noise and the other explain as much or less than random noise. I would go with Horn and keep the first 7 for an unsupervised view and if using as a pre-process method for supervised learning I would check the optimal number of PCs anyway by some model performance metric. But it would be hard for me to believe if model performance employed me to keep more than Horn's analyses suggested - so I would double check.